# OAuth issue (#200) on using facebook api - inviting users to a group

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

When I try to invite a user to my group I keep getting this

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#200) Requires extended permission: manage_groups",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 200
   }
}
```

error. I submit to `https://graph.facebook.com/GROUP_ID/members/USER_ID` with an app access token and the user I'm inviting is already member of the app.

So any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling with this too.

I believe the inviting user needs to authorize your app with the extended permission `manage_groups`. Basically request the following URL

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=<your_client_id>&redirect_uri=<your_redirect_url>&scope=manage_groups`

However, it does not grant the `manage_groups` permissions; it doesn't even present the user with the approval dialog. In fact, this permission is not mentioned at [Facebook Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/) help page, nor in the `permissions` [FQL table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/permissions) documentation. You can't add it to the app permissions in *App Settings -> Permissions* either. Neither is it available in *Graph Explorer*.

It is visible in the `permissions_info` table, though.

```
SELECT header, permission_name, summary 
FROM permissions_info 
WHERE permission_name IN ('manage_pages', 'manage_groups')

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fql_query_response xmlns="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" list="true">
  <permissions_info>
    <header>Manage Pages</header>
    <permission_name>manage_pages</permission_name>
    <summary>manage my pages</summary>
  </permissions_info>
  <permissions_info>
    <header>Manage Groups</header>
    <permission_name>manage_groups</permission_name>
    <summary>manage my groups</summary>
  </permissions_info>
</fql_query_response>
```

I tried the invited user to grant `manage_groups` permissions to the app, but it still doesn't work.

I'm out of ideas, tried everything but it seems this permission is still not taken into account by Facebook Login.

Answer (score 0):

So maybe it helps, if the app, with its app token creates the group then you can invite other users, which I did for a closed group but I [can't create a secret group](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1378732762347456) that's why I can't invite, if I invite users to a manually created group then I get the above issue.